# Using levenshtein in MySQL search for one result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to do a search on my MySQL database to get the row that contains the most similar value to the one searched for.

Even if the closest result is very different, I'd still like to return it (Later on I do a string comparison and add the 'unknown' into the learning pool)

I would like to search my table 'responses' via the 'msg1' column and get one result, the one with the lowest levenshtein score, as in the one that is the most similar out of the whole column.

This sort of thing:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE levenshtein('$message', 'msg1') ORDER BY ??? LIMIT 1
```

I don't quite grasp the concept of levenshtein here, as you can see I am searching the whole table, sorting it by ??? (the function's score?) and then limiting it to one result.

I'd then like to set $reply to the value in column "reply" from this singular row that I get.

Help would be greatly appreciated, I can't find many examples of what I'm looking for. I may be doing this completely wrong, I'm not sure.

Thank you!

Comment: IGNORE THIS, it's incorrect -->I believe you want to select the distance... Something like: 

SELECT MIN(distance) FROM (SELECT name, levenshtein(/../) as distance FROM people)...... Though, to be clear, I don't use MySQL often.

Comment: What about SOUNDEX? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM people p
ORDER BY levenshtein('$message', msg1) ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want a threshold (to limit the number of rows for sorting, then use a `WHERE` clause.  Otherwise, you just need `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Hi, I have used your code in my PDO block but it seems to be getting the top row of the database no matter what the $message variable is equal to (even if it is a 100% match to row 2)

Comment: @Jordan . . . Probably the quotes around `msg1`.  I took that from your original code, but that is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE levenshtein('$message', 'msg1') <= 0
```